# Enum implementing traits - memory issues?

Tags: java, groovy, memory-leaks, traits, dry

I'm trying to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) my code and I used for that, for the first time, `traits` to enhance my `enums`.

What I want to do, is : for a given array of strings, find all the enums matching at least one keyword (non case sensitive)

The code below seems to works fine, but I think it generates me memory leaks when the method `getSymbolFromIndustries` is called thousands of times.

Here is a capture from VisualVM after about 10 minutes of run, the column *Live Objects* is always increasing after each snapshot and the number of items compared to the second line is so huge...
[image: visual vm profiling]

My heap size is always increasing too...
[image: visual vm heap]

The trait :

```groovy
trait BasedOnCategories {
    String[] categories
    
    static getSymbolFromIndustries(Collection<String> candidates) {
        values().findAll {
            value -> !value.categories.findAll {
                categorie -> candidates.any {
                    candidate -> categorie.equalsIgnoreCase(candidate)
                }
            }
            .unique()
            .isEmpty()
        }
    }
}
```

One of the multiple enums I have implementing the `trait`

```groovy
enum KTC implements BasedOnCategories, BasedOnValues {
    KTC_01([
            'industries': ['Artificial Intelligence','Machine Learning','Intelligent Systems','Natural Language Processing','Predictive Analytics','Google Glass','Image Recognition', 'Apps' ],
            'keywords': ['AI','Voice recognition']
    ]),
    // ... more values
    KTC_43 ([
            'industries': ['Fuel','Oil and Gas','Fossil Fuels'],
            'keywords': ['Petroleum','Oil','Petrochemicals','Hydrocarbon','Refining']
    ]),
    // ... more values
    KTC_60([
            'industries': ['App Discovery','Apps','Consumer Applications','Enterprise Applications','Mobile Apps','Reading Apps','Web Apps','App Marketing','Application Performance Management', 'Apps' ],
            'keywords': ['App','Application']
    ])

    KTC(value) {
        this.categories = value.industries
        this.keywords = value.keywords
    }
```

My data-driven tests

```groovy
    def "GetKTCsFromIndustries"(Collection<String> actual, Enum[] expected) {
        expect:
        assert expected == KTC.getSymbolFromIndustries(actual)

        where:
        actual                                              | expected
        [ 'Oil and Gas' ]                                   | [KTC.KTC_43]
        [ 'oil and gas' ]                                   | [KTC.KTC_43]
        [ 'oil and gas', 'Fossil Fuels' ]                   | [KTC.KTC_43]
        [ 'oil and gas', 'Natural Language Processing' ]    | [KTC.KTC_01, KTC.KTC_43]
        [ 'apps' ]                                          | [KTC.KTC_01, KTC.KTC_60]
        [ 'xyo' ]                                           | []
    }
```

My questions :

- If someone have some clues to help me fix those leaks...
- Is there a more elegant way to write the `getSymbolFromIndustries` method ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about performance issues, but I would redesign your trait like that:

https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5205045624700928

```
trait BasedOnCategories {

    Set<String> categories
    
    void setCategories( Collection<String> cats ) {
        categories = new HashSet( cats*.toLowerCase() ).asImmutable()
    }

    @groovy.transform.Memoized
    static getSymbolFromIndustries(Collection<String> candidates) {
        def lowers = candidates*.toLowerCase()
        values().findAll{ value -> !lowers.disjoint( value.categories ) }
    }
}
```

Now the rest of the context

```
trait BasedOnValues {
    Set<String> keywords
}

enum KTC implements BasedOnCategories, BasedOnValues  {
    KTC_01([
            'industries': ['Artificial Intelligence','Machine Learning','Intelligent Systems','Natural Language Processing','Predictive Analytics','Google Glass','Image Recognition'],
            'keywords': ['AI','Voice recognition']
    ]),
    // ... more values
    KTC_43 ([
            'industries': ['Fuel','Oil and Gas','Fossil Fuels'],
            'keywords': ['Petroleum','Oil','Petrochemicals','Hydrocarbon','Refining']
    ]),
    // ... more values
    KTC_60([
            'industries': ['App Discovery','Apps','Consumer Applications','Enterprise Applications','Mobile Apps','Reading Apps','Web Apps','App Marketing','Application Performance Management'],
            'keywords': ['App','Application']
    ])

    KTC(value) {
        this.categories = value.industries
        this.keywords = value.keywords
    }
}

// some tests

[
    [ [ 'Oil and Gas' ], [KTC.KTC_43] ],
    [ [ 'oil and gas' ], [KTC.KTC_43] ],
    [ [ 'oil and gas', 'Fossil Fuels' ], [KTC.KTC_43] ],
    [ [ 'oil and gas', 'Natural Language Processing' ], [KTC.KTC_01, KTC.KTC_43] ],
    [ [ 'xyo' ], [] ],
].each{
    assert KTC.getSymbolFromIndustries( it[ 0 ] ) == it[ 1 ]
}
```

and then measure the performance

Comment: I like the way you clean the `trait` ! I never thinked about `@Memoized` nor a `Set` in groovy but I do it every time in node/react ^^ thanks for that already! 
I will do the benchmark asap and I will comment/approve your solution after the results ;) big thanks for taking time to review my code :)

Comment: added `disjoint` to make the code even simpler. In react btw I'm using tricks I learned from groovy ;)

Comment: This is true, `es6` and `groovy` have lot similarities ! :D
First results from the benchmark seems better, `Live Objects` are often cleaned, `Allocated Object` are still growing, I'll double check how I use the method to the if I forgot any "dead references"